# How to check/view data in SQL DB in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sqldb

I have a web app in azure which let user to input some data. I want to save them in sql db which I created in azure. Is there a way to check/view the entered data . I am referring to something like "mysql workbench for mysql"

Comment: use ssms to connect to azure and view the data,if that's what you meant by viewing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can download  sql server management studio to access your data.  Also you can you Visual Studio Community Edition or Visual Code.

Below is the link for download

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=828615

you also need to configure the sql database firewall to get access to your database. A Step by Step tutorial to configure that can be found in the following URL

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/

Comment: you also need to configure the sql database firewall to get access to your database.  A Step by Step tutorial to configure that can be found in the following URL   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/

Comment: Why would you duplicate a part of your answer in the comments section?

Answer (score 22):

You may also view the data in your browser using [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/)

Select your DB and then "Query editor" in the menu and start querying.

[image: ...]

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can query your database via SSMS: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-manage-azure-ssms/

Free to use: [MSDN SSMS download page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx)

Once connected to your database, simply right clicking on a table in the Object Explorer and selecting 'View top 1000 rows' would give you a view of - you guessed it- the top 1000 rows. You may query against the database there with any SQL query; For instance- removing the `TOP 1000` from the generated query will return all of the data in that table.

Comment: As of SQL 2016, SSMS is a separate download from SQL Server. If I'm not mistaken the license is now effectively free for developers.

Comment: @ShannonLowder : That's true! From the download page I linked: "This generally available release of SSMS is free and does not require a SQL Server license to install and use."